# RefinementResults not showing using Search 2013 API with anonymous connection

Tags: rest, search-api

First of all, I do get results even with selectproperties but RefinementResults give me a null value. Does anyone have a solution for it?

Url used is:

> **querytext**=%27AIVD%27&**selectproperties**=%27Title,InternetTeaserText,Nieuwstype,Afdeling,Kolom,Rubriek,InternetNewsDate,Path,InternetExpirationDate%27&**refiners**="Kolom"&**sortlist**=%27InternetNewsDate:descending%27&**QueryTemplatePropertiesUrl**=%27spfile://webroot/queryparametertemplate.xml%27

And gives me the right results (except for refinement):

```
{
    "d": {
        "query": {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchResult"
            },
            "ElapsedTime": 42,
            "PrimaryQueryResult": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.QueryResult"
                },
                "CustomResults": null,
                "QueryId": "4de58c7e-2fd5-440b-b5e4-429b89dd7b69",
                "QueryRuleId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "RefinementResults": null,
                "RelevantResults": {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "type": "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.RelevantResults"
                    },
                    "GroupTemplateId": null,
                    "ItemTemplateId": null,
                    "Properties": {
                        "results": [
                            {
                                "__metadata": {
                                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                },
                                "Key": "GenerationId",
                                "Value": "9223372036854775806",
                                "ValueType": "Edm.Int64"
                            },
                            {
                                "__metadata": {
                                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                },
                                "Key": "ExecutionTimeMs",
                                "Value": "16",
                                "ValueType": "Edm.Int32"
                            },
                            {
                                "__metadata": {
                                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                },
                                "Key": "QueryModification",
                                "Value": "AIVD -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople",
                                "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                            },
                            {
                                "__metadata": {
                                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                },
                                "Key": "RenderTemplateId",
                                "Value": "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Group_Default.js",
                                "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                            },
                            {
                                "__metadata": {
                                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                },
                                "Key": "piPageImpressionBlockType",
                                "Value": "2",
                                "ValueType": "Edm.Byte"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "ResultTitle": null,
                    "ResultTitleUrl": null,
                    "RowCount": 1,
                    "Table": {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "type": "SP.SimpleDataTable"
                        },
                        "Rows": {
                            "results": [
                                {
                                    "__metadata": {
                                        "type": "SP.SimpleDataRow"
                                    },
                                    "Cells": {
                                        "results": [
                                            {
                                                "__metadata": {
                                                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                                },
                                                "Key": "Rank",
                                                "Value": "0",
                                                "ValueType": "Edm.Double"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "__metadata": {
                                                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                                },
                                                "Key": "DocId",
                                                "Value": "2024",
                                                "ValueType": "Edm.Int64"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "__metadata": {
                                                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                                },
                                                "Key": "Title",
                                                "Value": "'Britse geheime dienst adviseerde AIVD over afluisteren'",
                                                "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "__metadata": {
                                                    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                                },
                                                "Key": "InternetTeaserText",
                                                "Value": "Britse geheime dienst GCHQ zou Nederlandse inlichtingendiensten AIVD en MIVD hebben geholpen een methode voor spionage via internet op te zetten. Ook op juridisch vlak zou de AIVD Britse hulp hebben gekregen.",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "Nieuwstype",
                                            "Value": "Intern",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "Afdeling",
                                            "Value": "Brandweerclusters",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "Kolom",
                                            "Value": "Brandweer",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "Rubriek",
                                            "Value": "Nieuws",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "InternetNewsDate",
                                            "Value": "2013-08-01T22:00:00.0000000Z",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.DateTime"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "Path",
                                            "Value": "http://www.xxxxxx.nl/Paginas/internet02.aspx",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "InternetExpirationDate",
                                            "Value": "2013-08-31T22:00:00.0000000Z",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.DateTime"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "OriginalPath",
                                            "Value": "http://www.xxxxxxx.nl/Paginas/internet02.aspx",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "FileType",
                                            "Value": "html",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "SecondaryFileExtension",
                                            "Value": "aspx",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "Author",
                                            "Value": null,
                                            "ValueType": "Null"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "Size",
                                            "Value": "180844",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.Int64"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "Description",
                                            "Value": null,
                                            "ValueType": "Null"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "EditorOWSUSER",
                                            "Value": null,
                                            "ValueType": "Null"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "LastModifiedTime",
                                            "Value": "2013-11-27T07:45:39.0000000Z",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.DateTime"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "CollapsingStatus",
                                            "Value": "0",
                                            "ValueType": "Edm.Int64"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "__metadata": {
                                                "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                                            },
                                            "Key": "HitHighlightedSummary",
                                            "Value": "Britse geheime dienst adviseerde AIVD over afluisteren'\r\nTeaser tekst: \r\n\t\t\t\r\n\u00a0\r\nInhoud\n gelekte stukken omschrijven de Britten de AIVD en MIVD als "kleinnaarBritsemaatstaven","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"HitHighlightedProperties","Value":null,"ValueType":"Null"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"FileExtension","Value":"aspx","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"ViewsLifeTime","Value":null,"ValueType":"Null"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"ParentLink","Value":"http: //www.vrijsselland.nl/Paginas/Forms/AllItems.aspx","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"ViewsRecent","Value":null,"ValueType":"Null"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"IsContainer","Value":"false","ValueType":"Edm.Boolean"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"DisplayAuthor","Value":null,"ValueType":"Null"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"docaclmeta","Value":null,"ValueType":"Null"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"ResultTypeIdList","Value":"16","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"PartitionId","Value":"0c37852b-34d0-418e-91c6-2ac25af4be5b","ValueType":"Edm.Guid"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"UrlZone","Value":"0","ValueType":"Edm.Int32"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"AAMEnabledManagedProperties","Value":"AttachmentURI;deeplinks;DefaultEncodingURL;ExternalMediaURL;HierarchyUrl;OrgParentUrls;OrgUrls;OriginalPath;ParentLink;Path;PictureThumbnailURL;PictureURL;PublishingImage;recommendedfor;ServerRedirectedEmbedURL;ServerRedirectedPreviewURL;ServerRedirectedURL;SiteLogo;SitePath;SPSiteURL;UserEncodingURL","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"ResultTypeId","Value":"16","ValueType":"Edm.Int32"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"RenderTemplateId","Value":"~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/DisplayTemplates/Search/Item_WebPage.js","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"piSearchResultId","Value":"0_1","ValueType":"Edm.String"}]}}]}},"TotalRows":1,"TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates":1},"SpecialTermResults":null},"Properties":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"RowLimit","Value":"10","ValueType":"Edm.Int32"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SourceId","Value":"8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89","ValueType":"Edm.Guid"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"piPageImpression","Value":"86762_3866_1043","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"IsCached","Value":"false","ValueType":"Edm.Boolean"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SerializedQuery","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"}]},"SecondaryQueryResults":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"type":"Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.QueryResult"},"CustomResults":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"type":"Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.CustomResult"},"GroupTemplateId":null,"ItemTemplateId":null,"Properties":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"ExecutionTimeMs","Value":"0","ValueType":"Edm.Int32"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"QueryModification","Value":"AIVD","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"RenderTemplateId","Value":"~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/DisplayTemplates/Search/Group_Default.js","ValueType":"Edm.String"}]},"ResultTitle":"PERSOONLIJKEFAVORIETEN","ResultTitleUrl":null,"Table":{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.SimpleDataTable"},"Rows":{"results":[]}},"TableType":"PersonalFavoriteResults"}]},"QueryId":"PersonalFavoriteQuery","QueryRuleId":"563b0322-36af-4bcd-a400-00e5e81e0b31","RefinementResults":null,"RelevantResults":null,"SpecialTermResults":null}]},"SpellingSuggestion":"","TriggeredRules":{"results":[]}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Security Trimming all the way :)

Comment: Could you argue why and where to use Security Trimming? That may help future visitors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue on SP 2019 and adding `<a:string>Refiners</a:string>` element into the whitelist part in `queryparametertemplate.xml` resolved it.